# Unit Test not running

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm getting stuck with some unittests.

Here's the simplest example I could come up with:

```
#testito.py
import unittest

class Prueba(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass
    def printsTrue(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__=="__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Problem is, running this has no effect:

```
$ python testito.py 

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

I'm scratching my head as I don't see any problem with the code above.
It happened with a couple of tests now and I don't really know what to do next.
Any idea?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

By default, only functions whose name that start with `test` are run:

```
class Prueba(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass
    def testPrintsTrue(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

From the [unittest basic example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#basic-example):

> A testcase is created by subclassing `unittest.TestCase`. The three individual tests are defined with methods whose names start with the letters `test`. This naming convention informs the test runner about which methods represent tests.

Comment: just wandering why testPrints instead of test_prints

Comment: @FooBarUser: I was sticking to the existing naming convention of the original question.

Comment: Doesn't work for me even adding test at the beginning of the function. It's just the same as this, but 0 tests are run...

Comment: @darkgaze: can you make the example in the question work, with my correction? What are the concrete differences between that and your setup? I can't really assess what goes wrong in your case with this little information, if you can't get it to work, ask a new question. Be sure to include a [mcve].

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm using python through the scripting panel on Maya. It uses python 2.7, and I can run any python code from there. I tried to run the test using the console and the test was run... But failed anyway. I'm trying to find out why.

Comment: Any recommendations for getting around this default behavior? Say a new developer begins working on the code, adds a test case, sees everything passing, but does not realize his test was not included. Is there any way to alert the developer to the fact that their function is not being tested? Or force all methods under 'TestCase' to be tested?

Comment: @ScottSkiles: you'd have to define your own `TestLoader` subclass, overriding the [`getTestCaseNames()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.getTestCaseNames). The [current implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/unittest/loader.py#L222-L232) makes this a little simpler; you can also set the [`testMethodPrefix` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.testMethodPrefix) on an existing loader.

Comment: @ScottSkiles: Some [helper functions in `unittest.loader`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/unittest/loader.py#L497-L508) do just that.

Comment: @ScottSkiles: to alert that there are methods on a `TestCase` not being run, you'd have to do your own analysis; enumerate all methods on the classes that are not matching a whitelist and don't match the pattern.

Comment: and it has to be lowercase test too - just wasted 30 minutes on this!