# Python 2 unit tests not running from command line

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing

I have the following project structure:

```
my_project
├── __init__.py
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── particle.py
│   ├── position.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── test_particle.py
    ├── test_position.py
```

All of the `__init__.py` files are empty.

As an example, `test_particle.py` looks like:

```
import unittest
from src.particle import Particle

class TestParticle(unittest.TestCase):
    def first_test(self):
        particle = Particle("A")
        self.assertEqual(particle.type, "A")
...

if __name__=='__main__':
      unittest.main()
```

None of my tests will run with the command `python -m unittest discover -v tests`. If I rename the `first_test` method to `runTest`, that one test does actually run. How do I get Python to run all of my tests and not just whatever is in `runTest`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit Test not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626524/unit-test-not-running)

Comment: What is your exact output ? I've made a fast test and the command python -m unittest discover -v tests it works (using def first_test and self.assertEqual(1,1). I've run this comand outside the folder tests (naturally) 
--------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK